# Is there a way to connect to office VPN using parallels (windows) but surf on host Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, vpn, parallels-desktop

My office VPN called Juniper does not gets installed on Mac OS X. I am using Parallels to run guest Windows on my macbook pro with OS X Yosemite. I don't know what I am asking, and if it is even logical or not, but here is my question:

Is there a way that I can share my guest operating system's VPN connection with host operating system? What I mean is, that I connect to my office VPN using my guest Parallels Windows OS and that can be shared with my host macbook Mac OS X?

By doing this what I want to achieve is, that I want to just open Windows using Parallels and then connect to my VPN and then minimize it and come back to OS X and then surf all my internet websites on Safari or Chrome (on Mac and not W indows).

Is this possible? Could anybody guide me on how to do this if its possible?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to share the connection from Windows to Mac, depending upon how it is implemented in Windows. Follow these steps, from [this site](http://caliduscommunications.com/blog/?p=17):

1. Add a Host-Only network adapter to the guest (Windows).
2. Launch the Guest (Windows).
3. Go to a command prompt and type:

   ```
   ipconfig /all
   ```

   Note the IP Address of the Host Only adapter. Likely something like 10.37.129.2.
4. *Assuming the VPN shows as a connection in Windows Network Connections*, setup Internet Connection Sharing on this adapter. When setting up ICS, choose the Host Only adapter as the Private Network Adapter.
5. Once that’s done, connect to the VPN.
6. On the host, add a route to your VPN, specifying the IP address of the Host Only Adapter as the gateway. In this example, the subnet trying to be reached on the VPN is 192.168.40.0/24, and the IP address of the Host Only Adapter is 10.37.129.2, so in a Terminal window you would type the following:

   ```
   sudo route -n add 192.168.40.0/24 10.37.129.3
   ```

Comment: By definition this setup can't work. A [host-only adapter](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/22243.htm) connects to a closed internal virtual network with no internet connection. As a result you can't set up any working VPN connection to a VPN-server using this interface. You need at least a 2nd interface - probably a bridge to eth0/eth1

Comment: @tubedogg Thanks for your efforts for finding this information. Could you also share how to undo these changes if they don't wory?

Comment: @klanomath could you please suggest a better way if it exists to do this?

Comment: This solution did work for me. Just several notices:
1. after VPN connection established, I had to run "net stop sharedaccess & net start sharedaccess"
2. yes, another network connection should be added to guest machine, otherwise it has no internet connection
3. you have a typo in a "sudo route..." - gateway IP should be exactly  the same as guest IP

Comment: @AlexeyF, have you used a bridged network in VM?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like I have similar hardware and software setup. Are you able to setup VPN through the Mac's system preferences?

1. Go **System Preferences** >> **Network**
2. At the bottom-left, click '**+**' to create a new type of connection.
3. For the **Interface** drop-list, choose **VPN**
4. Choose the **VPN Type** accordingly.
5. Confirm that **Service Name** is meaningful for you.
6. Complete the remaining fields according to your setup.
7. Tick the **Show VPN status in menu bar** checkbox.

Once that's done, go to the menu bar and click the "VPN" icon and choose **Connect**. If you want to manually end the session, then you'll be able to choose **Disconnect**.

Comment: I don't know VPN type or Service name for my company's VPN. They do not share it, once I open a website, and login with my credentials they install a Juniper vpn software on my windows machine (it doesn't support Mac). But once my windows (parallels virtual desktop) is connected to vpn can I share this connection on mac as well? this is my question.